# Docker: exposing port on container IP

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to expose a port on a Docker container without having to map it to a port on the host; this works fine for the likes of sql databases or web systems such as redmine where I can access Redmine on port 3000 of the containers IP address from the host system without mapping the port.

My Dockerfile looks something like this (volumes, envs, etc removed for "clarity")

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN pip install gunicorn

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "myapp.wsgi" ]
```

This should tell gunicorn to bind (-b) to port 8000 or all addresses; so I expected port 8000 to be open on the container when I run it with say

```
docker run myappthing
```

But no - even tho gunicorn is running happily. Yet if I do

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8028:8000 myappthing
```

Then not only is port 8028 open on the host but 8000 is open on the container too.

Whats going on here; what have I missed?

Thanks

`docker ps` report ports differently as below: redmine and mysql show they are not mapped to a port on the host where my attempt is mapped

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                   CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                      NAMES
b68765d57f0b        52adec2834c2        "gunicorn -b 172.18.…"    45 minutes ago      Up 45 minutes       127.0.0.1:8028->8000/tcp   afc-timerec-manual
aaecd3cd319d        9671544d5284        "/docker-entrypoint.…"    7 months ago        Up 7 weeks          3000/tcp                   afc-redmine
fb4e55d352b2        1571059e8458        "docker-entrypoint.s…"    13 months ago       Up 4 days           3306/tcp                   afc-glpi-data
```

More illustrations: if I open a shell on the container, I can do this:

```
lynx http://127.0.0.1:8000
lynx http://172.18.0.28:8000
```

(where 172.18.0.28 is the container IP address) and both commands allow me to access the webapp.

Meanwhile, back on the host - port 8000 is not open on the container so `lynx http://172.18.0.28:8000` fails

Answer (score 1):

The port is not published using the `EXPOSE` instruction, you need to use `-p`.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose

> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running
>   the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or
>   more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them
>   to high-order ports.

Comment: Thanks, I get that - but how do other containers expose their ports without -p during run: for example redmine has port 3000 open but I did not specify -p when I started the container. And it is reported differently in `docker ps` (I will add an example above...

Comment: @Mack Ports are exposed with EXPOSE image instruction. The `-p` argument isn't for exposing, but publishing.
The main difference is: - exposing means the port can be connected to by other containers in the same network, - publishing means the already exposed port is mapped to the host.

As you saw with `docker ps`, the first row/container has published (and exposed) ports and the 2nd and 3rd rows show exposed ports.

Comment: The only reason I can think of why EXPOSEd ports are also open on the host (as you described) is when the docker network and the host network have been bridged, which is probably not a good thing to do..

Comment: @Christian: I thought I had figured it there by connecting the container to its user network but I confused myself. The port is only open to the host when I specify -p unlike the redmine container - so I am no further forward

Comment: Well as you see from running `docker ps`, that shouldn't be happening. Maybe check Docker info?